# Setting up an LP problem on producing linear board in jumbo reels

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, constraints

I have to set up a linear programming problem corresponding to the following scenario:

---

[image]

---

What I tried:

I think we have 8 templates for 1 $68 \times l$ reel (or whatever):

1. $22,22,22$ (66)
2. $20,20,20$ (60)
3. $12,12,12,12,12$ (60)
4. $22,22,20$ (64)
5. $22,20,20$ (62)
6. $22,20,12,12$ (66)
7. $22,12,12,12$ (58)
8. $12,12,12,12,20$ (68)

Let $x_{i,j}$ denote order $j$ from type $i$

for $i = 1,2,...,8$

for $j = 1,2,3$

We want to minimise reels (or whatever) used

$$z = \sum_i \sum_j x_{i,j}$$

s.t.

Nonnegativity:

1. $$x_{i,j} \ge 0$$

Orders:

1. $$\sum_i x_{i,1} \ge 110$$
2. $$\sum_i x_{i,2} \ge 120$$
3. $$\sum_i x_{i,3} \ge 80$$

---

Is that right?

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach, reduce all possible combinations how to cut the jumbo reels to a couple of useful order type cuts, looks very good to me.

**Optimization Goal:**

Your optimization goal is wrong. You are requested to minimize trim waste.

For this you just need to define the amount of trim waste $w_i$ for each order type $i$ and sum this up multiplied with the order type amounts $x_i$.
E.g. $w_1 = 68\cdot L - 66 \cdot L = 2 \cdot L$. We would just count it in multiples of the fixed length $L$, so we simply say $w_1 = 2$.

Our goal of minimized total waste might be written as:
$$
\min w = \min \sum_i w_i \, x_i
$$

**The Constraints:**

For each order type $i$ you can define a quantity $n_{ij}$, which describes how many type $j$ reels result from an order of type $i$.
E.g. $n_2 = = (n_{21}, n_{22}, n_{23}) = (0, 3, 0)$, $n_6 = (1,1,2)$.

The constraint of the ordered $j$ reel amounts is e.g.
$$
\sum_i n_{i1} x_i \ge 110
$$

**Trim Waste Revisited:**

Having those $n_{ij}$ will give you the trim wastes
$$
w_i = 68 - 22 \cdot n_{i1} - 20 \cdot n_{i2} - 12 \cdot n_{i3}
$$

**Order Types:**

Important for your result is the choice of the order types, which are represented by the $n_{ij}$. 
You defined $8$ of them, I do not know if there are more useful order types.
I would consider all with a resulting trim waste 
$$
0 \le w_i < 12
$$
and
$$
n_{ij} \ge 0
$$
but different from the null vector.
I would write a small script to determine all by brute force.

**Update:**

My friend Ruby found $10$ order types, see [here](https://gist.github.com/1ec56bfaf93d2acd61642eb1a93f89a8). ([Source](https://gist.github.com/5639408354c036696316c2c9d80fe305))

Comment: Thanks so much mvw! ^-^ Is your script related to the knapsack problem? I think I learned something like that in a programming class in undergrad

Comment: I think it is not the Knapsack problem, because I was not looking for an optimum, just for all divisions of $68$ such that the trim waste is not sufficient for another roll, that is why the condition is $w < 12$.

Comment: mvw, I finally looked over this again. I think it's $n_2 = (0,3,0)$ not $(0,5,0)$ ? Once again, thanks ^-^

Comment: Btw mvw, so your script checks 0,0,0 then 0,0,1 then 0,0,2 and so on? In that case, do you really need $N=68$? I think we could say 5 from the beginning because $n_{ij} \ge 6$ would be impossible :P

Comment: Thanks, I corrected $n_2$.

Comment: It was just a pessimistic assumption for a brute force search, which guarantees to include all solutions and is still easy to handle for a machine.

Comment: Right thanks mvw :P

Comment: mvw, what happened to the script?

Comment: No idea. I might have accidentally deleted it. I try to re-add it to the answer.

Comment: @BCLC I rewrote the brute force script and put it on a new site.

Comment: thanks ^-^ might you please check out my other unanswered operations research questions? Some have bounties